# where can I download the ispell *.dict and *.affix files?

Tags: dictionary, full-text-search, nlp, ispell

I am quite new to postgresql full text search and I am setting up the configuration as where can I download the ispell *.dict and *.affix filefollowing (exactly as in [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html)):

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY english_ispell (
    TEMPLATE = ispell,
    DictFile = english, 
    AffFile = english, 
    StopWords = english
);
```

So, this I think expects files `english.dict` and `english.affix` on for example:

```
/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/tsearch_data
```

But these files are not there. I just have `ispell_sample.dict` and `ispell_sample.affix` - which when included above work fine - no problem.

So... I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300874/tsvector-only-supports-english) and downloaded the required dictionary from [the open office people](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/english-dictionaries-apache-openoffice) and renamed the `.dic` to `.dict` and `.aff` to `.affix`. Then I have checked (using `file -bi dict.affix` and `file -bi english.dict` and they are UTF8 encoded).

When I run the above text search dictionary, I get the error:

```
 ERROR:  wrong affix file format for flag
 CONTEXT:  line 2778 of configuration file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/tsearch_data/english.affix": "COMPOUNDMIN 1
 "
```

I was wondering if anyone had clues on how to solve this problem or if anyone had encountered this before..
Thanks./.

UPDATE:1: I guess the question can be rephrased as follows:
`where can I download the ispell *.dict and *.affix file for postgres`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a good reference: https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/ispell-dictionaries.html This is a good resource for those dictionaries of any language.

Comment: some link inside that link are not work properly, i already give other solution instead

Answer (score 1):

### Here's complete and latest dic and aff file:

https://github.com/albasyir/dictionaries

### Already Served on Network

those files already served on https://albasyir.github.io/dictionaries/, and here's example if you using typo-js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/typo-js) you can access with this example url:

- https://albasyir.github.io/dictionaries/en/en_US.aff
- https://albasyir.github.io/dictionaries/en/en_US.dic

this the URL pattern if you need other language:

- [https://albasyir.github.io/dictionaries/{path](https://albasyir.github.io/dictionaries/%7Bpath) folder on repository}